# Link MSProject Tasks to Azure Devops WorkITems

Tags: azure-devops, ms-project

Just getting started with Azure DevOps and finding myself entering and updating stuff twice: MS Project project plans and Azure Devops Work items (work done, estimated remaining)

I can;t find anything about being able to link  a WorkItem in Project and Azure DevOps (project is published with Sharepoint online)

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I'm coming along in dec 2022 looking to answer the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/create-your-backlog-tasks-using-project?view=tfs-2018&tabs=office-365#add-tasks-and-publish-work-items) states how to integrate Microsoft Project with Azure devops.

If you want to first import a list or tree of work items you've already defined, follow steps 3 and 4 under [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel, Add work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=tfs-2018#add-work-items). In the New list dialog, select the Query that contains the work items you want to import.

With the work items of azure devops are imported,you can add tasks. When you indent tasks and then publish your plan, you create parent-child links between work items.
[image]

To see the parent-child links that you just created, open Links and Attachments.

Answer (score 0):

(July 2022) Microsoft devops's user guide states that

*"Starting with Visual Studio 2019, the Team Foundation plug-in for Office is deprecating support for Microsoft Project. Project integration and the TFSFieldMapping command is not supported for Azure DevOps Server 2019 nor for Azure DevOps Services. However, you can continue to use Microsoft Excel."*
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/tools?view=azure-devops)

So a short answer may be "No."...
But you may want to check i.e.
[Integration between Azure Devops 2019 and MS Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372314/integration-between-azure-devops-2019-and-ms-project)
https://www.theprojectgroup.com/fr/middleware/integration-devops-tfs
Or an alternative to MsPorject : "projectmanager"...