# Integration between Azure Devops 2019 and MS Project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops-server-2019

According to Microsoft documentation, integration between TFS and MS Project is deprecated from VS / TFS 2019 forward. Can u please let us know what the alternative solution is to sync between gants in MS Project and TFS. Thank u

From Microsoft Documentation :
Starting with Visual Studio 2019 and Azure DevOps Office® Integration 2019, support for Microsoft Project is deprecated. Project integration and the TFSFieldMapping command aren't supported for Azure DevOps Server 2019 nor for Azure DevOps Services. However, full support for Microsoft Excel integration is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation: full support for Microsoft Excel integration is maintained. So to support your work tracking work, you can use Microsoft Excel as an alternative. To work in Excel, see [Bulk add work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=agile-process).

Working in Project is similar to publishing and refreshing work items using Office Excel, with a few differences as described in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/create-your-backlog-tasks-using-project?view=tfs-2018&tabs=office-365#differences-working-in-project-versus-excel).

[image]

According to the differences between Project and Excel, Excel is more superior than Project.

Though Excel doesn’t have a predefined Gantt chart type, you can create one using this free template: [Gantt project planner template for Excel](https://templates.office.com/en-us/Gantt-project-planner-TM02887601?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Excel doesn't seem to have vital features Project has, e.g. critical path identification and display, integration of multiple projects within same MS Project, etc...

Comment: Thank u for your response. It seems that the official third-party support relates only to Project Server whereas we're relating to simple ms-project client program (without server). Can u please relate to this ? It would be helpful and BTW we're using On Premise TFS. Thank u

Comment: There is currently no official Microsoft document describing alternatives to the ms project, but some [third-party](https://thedigitalprojectmanager.com/microsoft-project-alternatives/#overviews) sites have information on paid & free Microsoft Project Alternatives,you can refer to.